# Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?

Tags: publications

Using a link as a reference is often problematic as the link might disappear at a future time. However, the content might be of high relevance to the reader, so it might be worthwhile to add it as a reference. Do some publishers offer to host a mirror of webpages used as a reference?

Answer (score 2):

Some publishers integrate with WebCite to help ensure web references remain persistent: http://www.webcitation.org/.

> "WebCite ... is an on-demand archiving system for webreferences (cited
>   webpages and websites, or other kinds of Internet-accessible digital
>   objects), which can be used by authors, editors, and publishers of
>   scholarly papers and books, to ensure that cited webmaterial will
>   remain available to readers in the future."

BioMed Central [ran a blog article](http://blogs.biomedcentral.com/bmcblog/2007/09/17/webcite-links-provide-access-to-archived-copy-of-linked-web-pages/) in 2007 that discussed integration with WebCite. The blog article provides [an example of a webpage](http://www.webcitation.org/query.php?url=http://www.thebiogrid.org&refdoi=10.1186/jbiol36) archived using the service.

I'm not clear of the current status of WebCite and how widely it is now used. From the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebCite) it sounds like there have been funding issues in recent years.

Comment: Nice great to hear.

Comment: Investigating a little more...oddly [the article mentioned](http://jbiol.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/jbiol36) in the BioMedCentral blog links to the [current version of the BioGrid website](http://thebiogrid.org/), not [the archived version](http://www.webcitation.org/query.php?url=http://www.thebiogrid.org&refdoi=10.1186/jbiol36).

Comment: From a *quick* glance at other BioMed Central articles, I haven't seen the WebCite logo appearing next to web references, so perhaps they no longer use the service.